# Why my json data doesn't show noting in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this code but when I try to run it noting happens.
I have a webservice that return a json with some data and I need to list it on a app.

My app.js is:

```
(function (){
    var app = angular.module("opoBUS");
    app.controller("StopCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$ionicLoading", "DataStore", function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, DataStore) {
        var self = this;
        this.linhas = [];

        this.getLinhas = function () {
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Loading...'
            });
            $http.get("http://www.stcp.pt/pt//itinerarium/callservice.php?action=lineslist")
            .success(function (data) {
                    self.linhas = data;
                    DataStore.linhas = self.linhas;
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                })
            .error(function (error) {
                    DataStore.linhas.length = 0;
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                });
    };
    this.adicionarFavorito = function(linha){
            DataStore.adicionarFavorito(linha);
        };
        if (DataStore.linhas.length === 0) {
            this.getLinhas();
        }
    }]);
})();
```

And my paragem.html is:

```
<ion-view view-title="Paragem">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">
        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="StopCtrl.getLinhas()">
        </ion-refresher>
        <ion-list>
            <div class="list card" collection-repeat="linha in StopCtrl.linhas">
                <div class="item item-avatar">
                    <h2>{{linha.code}}</h2>
                    <p>Description {{linha.description}}</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item item-body">
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="subdued">{{linha.pubcode}}</a>
                        <a href="#" class="subdued">Codigo {{linha.code}}</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-list>        
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It is suppose to devolve a list with all information inside the json.

Comment: can you move this to a codePen? would make it easier to see the issue, also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
self.linhas = data;
```

to

```
self.linhas = data.records
```

Semi-functioning codepen here... http://codepen.io/aaronksaunders/pen/grGJvw?editors=1010

you will need a CORS plugin for your browser to get the codepen to work